# how to define parameter of the type with jquery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have two data on this different link

Link 1

`/api/products?type=tour_package`

Data1

```
[{"id":"-1","type":"tour_package","name":"Hello World"},
{"id":"1","type":"tour_package","name":"My title"}]
```

Link 2

`/api/products?type=nontour_product`

Data2

```
[{"id":"-1","type":"nontour_product","name":"Korea Tickets"}]
```

I want to show the value in the input box

My Code is

```
$('#product_name').autocomplete({ 
  source: function( request, response ) {
    url = "/api/products?type=" + request.term;

    $.getJSON( url , function(data) {
      response(data);
    });                 
  },
  minLength: 3, 
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    $($(this).data('target')).val(ui.item[ 'type' ]);
    $(event.currentTarget).val(ui.item[ 'name' ]);
  } 
});
```

HTML code

```
<tr>
  <td><?= form_dropdown('product_type', array(
                          'custom' => 'Custom',
                          'tour_package' => 'Tour',
                          'nontour_product' => 'Generic',
                          'flight' => 'Flight',
                          'hotel_room' => 'Hotel'
                        )); ?>
  </td>
  <td><?= form_input(array('data-property'=>'product_name','style'=>'width:70px;','id'=>'product_name')) ?></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger on what link to access is based on the changing of your "product_type"  dropdown so it might go like this...

```
$('#product_type').change(function(){
    var productType = $("#product_type").val();
    var url = "/api/products?type=" + productType;

    $('#product_name').autocomplete({
        source:url,
        minLength: 3,
        select: function( event, ui ) {

            $($(this).data('target')).val(ui.item[ 'type' ]);
            $(event.currentTarget).val(ui.item[ 'name' ]);
        }

    });
});
```